# get the incorrect data from serializer.data

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

i want to get the data (amount) from serializer but the serializer get back the none.
but when i get the date from the request data i get the correct data.can someone help to solve this issue??

this is the response body of serializer data and request data.  got the {'amount': 1000000} the request body and the {'amount': None} from serialized data:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
August 23, 2022 - 16:19:21
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
{'amount': 1000000}
{'amount': None}
Internal Server Error: /api/zarinpal/request/
Traceback (most recent
```

this is the function get the request

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def request_to_pay(request):
    data = request.data
    print(data)
    serializer = RequestToPaySerializer(data=data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    print(serializer.data)
```

and this is the serializer class:

```
class RequestToPaySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    amount = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=3)
    description = serializers.CharField(required=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is because the requested data validation failed and no data represented in the serializer, first print show it prints data with only amount now description is required so I suggest doing view as follows

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def request_to_pay(request):
    data = request.data
    print(data)
    serializer = RequestToPaySerializer(data=data)
    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        return Response(data=serializer.data, status=200)
    print(serializer.error) # incase you want to show error
    return Response (data=serializer.error,status=400)
```

> or you can make a description field not required in serializer